# Using pygal Value configuration with DateTimeLine

Tags: python, pygal

I'm plotting some CPU time statistics and would like to be able to annotate certain values. I wanted to use [pygal's value configuration](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/configuration/value.html) for this, but this does not seem to work in combination with the [DateTimeLine](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/xy.html#datetime) chart I am using.

```py
def generate_cpu_time_plot(csv_file_path, output_file):
    user = []
    system = []
    with open(csv_file_path, encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(row['time_millis']) / 1000)
            user.append((time, {
                'value': float(row['cpu_time_user'])
            }))
            system.append((time, {
                'value': float(row['cpu_time_system'])
            }))

    chart = pygal.DateTimeLine(x_label_rotation=35,
                               x_value_formatter=lambda dt: dt.strftime(
                                   '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'), x_title='Time',
                               y_title='CPU time',
                               title=os.path.basename(csv_file_path))
    chart.add("User", user)
    chart.add("System", system)
    chart.render_to_file(output_file)
```

This gives me a TypeError: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'`

Is there a way I can make this combination work? If I use the floats directly, without the dict, this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The tuple containing the x and y values you provide to the XY chart is *the* value.  When you use the `dict` format for providing values you need to set the `value` property to this tuple.

At the moment your code tries to put a `dict` for the y value within the tuple.  Changing the lines where the values are appended to the `user` and `system` lists to the following should fix it:

```
user.append({'value': (time, float(row['cpu_time_user']))})
system.append({'value': (time, float(row['cpu_time_system']))})
```